# Using packages installed from quicklisp with clisp

Tags: common-lisp, clisp, quicklisp

I installed [cl-yacc](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jch/software/cl-yacc/) from [quick lisp](http://www.quicklisp.org):

```
(ql:quickload "yacc")
```

I checked it is available.

```
[12]> (ql:system-apropos "yacc")
#<SYSTEM lispbuilder-yacc / lispbuilder-20130312-svn / quicklisp 2013-08-13>
#<SYSTEM yacc / cl-yacc-20101006-darcs / quicklisp 2013-08-13>
```

I tried to use the package, but I got errors.

```
[18]> (use-package '#:yacc)

*** - USE-PACKAGE: There is no package with name "YACC"
The following restarts are available:
USE-VALUE      :R1      Input a value to be used instead.
ABORT          :R2      Abort main loop

[20]> (use-package 'yacc)

*** - USE-PACKAGE: There is no package with name "YACC"
The following restarts are available:
USE-VALUE      :R1      Input a value to be used instead.
ABORT          :R2      Abort main loop
```

What might be wrong? How to use the package?
I use clisp under Mac OS X 10.7.5

Comment: Does it work if you call `(asdf:load-system :yacc)` prior to `use-package`?  Not sure if it needs to be a keyword or a string for `load-system`.

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks for your hint. That was it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be two ways to do it.

#### ql:quickload

```
[1]> (ql:quickload "yacc")
To load "yacc":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    yacc
; Loading "yacc"

("yacc")
[2]> (use-package 'yacc)
T
```

#### asdf:load-system

```
[1]> (asdf:load-system :yacc)
0 errors, 0 warnings
T
[2]> (use-package 'yacc)
T
```